# jQuery noConflict IE issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a widget that depends on jquery being loaded - I'm using the following to load it and my code:

```
(function () {

    var jqueryVersion = (window.jQuery !== undefined) ? window.jQuery.fn.jquery.charAt(0) + window.jQuery.fn.jquery.charAt(2) : 0;

    var jQuery;
    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
        main();
    }

    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
    if (parseInt(jqueryVersion) < 17) {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js");
        script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // Same thing but for IE
            if (this.readyState === 'complete' || this.readyState === 'loaded') { scriptLoadHandler(); }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script_tag);
    } else {
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }

    function main() {
        //my code goes in here
        //leaving blank for now because I still get error
    }

})();
```

I got most of that from here: http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/

I need jquery 1.7 or higher because I use the .on() method.  When I run this on a page using jquery that is older than 1.7 I sometimes get errors in IE that lead me to believe there is a conflict with either the old version of jquery or some other js on the page.  Some errors:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'forceInt' of undefined or null reference

SCRIPT5007: Object expected

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'easing' of undefined or null reference

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'

These errors go away if I change

```
jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

to

```
jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: your `jQueryVersion` check is going to go badly wrong when v 1.10 is released.

Comment: out of interest, is there no chance of upgrading the main jQuery in the site? Having multiple jQuery versions on the same site does work (thanks to `.noConflict`), but it's a lot of extra download if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem might be caused by the fact that the 'handler' is called twice.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180173(v=vs.85).aspx

Also, taken from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

> "If necessary, you can free up the jQuery name as well by passing true
>   as an argument to the method. This is rarely necessary, and if you
>   must do this (for example, if you need to use multiple versions of the
>   jQuery library on the same page), you need to consider that most
>   plug-ins rely on the presence of the jQuery variable and may not
>   operate correctly in this situation."

Comment: Since this widget goes on other people's sites I don't want to have to have them update their jQuery version in addition to adding the widget.  I thought the point of `var jQuery;` was to localize that variable.  Should I store the jQuery i'm loading as another variable?  Would I then not need to pass `true` in `noConflict()`

Comment: @user1114701, I updated the answer, try aliasing it to a new variable and use that new variable instead.

Comment: Well while trying to figure this out I noticed that scriptLoadHandler() was getting called twice in IE > 8. I set up a conditional where IE uses `script_tag.onreadystatechange` and everone else uses `script_tag.onload` and the problem seems to be solved. Any idea why?

Comment: Not sure, could it be because IE supports both. In that case, the handler would be called twice.

Comment: @user1114701, added a reference that explains what might have occured.